# Port 80 not open. Still gets 404 when curl

Tags: linux, http, port, tcp, curl

Weird issue I'm facing currently! There is nothing running on port 80.

Still curl gives 404 page not found.  I can telnet to port 80 and even start a container exposing port 80 (host). But no requests reaches the container!

Any idea what might be going on? How do I debug this?

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep :80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
$ curl localhost
404 page not found
```

Comment: Please provide output of `iptables -vnL -t nat` or `nft list ruleset ip` as theres possibly a internal nat redirect causing that behaviour.

Comment: It was indeed because of iptables rule. I had installed k3s which configures some iptables rules. Uninstalling it solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Matthew's comment suspecting internal nat redirect

- `iptables -vnL -t nat` or `nft list ruleset ip`

perhaps you could directly inspect port 80. These are some of the ways to do that:

- `ss -4tlnp -o state LISTENING '( sport = :80 )'`
- `lsof -i:80`
- do a verbose tcpdump
- do a verbose portscan with nmap
- or, be even more explicit when testing with curl, ie `curl -v http://localhost:80`

Comment: I would add `curl` with `-v` option to the top of this list.